# ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied anonymous and Windows auth IIS

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, entity-framework

I have an issue when connecting to Oracle DB in the following scenario:

**Connection String:**

```
<add name="PassContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.PassModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.PassModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.PassModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=DB-SCAN:1521/PR;USER ID=/;Pooling=true;CONNECTION LIFETIME=20;INCR POOL SIZE=1;MAX POOL SIZE=1;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

In the development environment, everything is working fine.

When I publish to IIS this is what happened:

We used Anonymous and Windows Auth

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
<identity impersonate="true" />
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" /> 
</authorization>
```

I have multiple access level in the same site :

> Pages/* Windows Auth
>
> Public/* anonymouse auth

in the public folder i used another dbcontext with a connection string with user name and password :

```
<add name="PublicPassContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.PassModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.PassModel.ssdl|res://*/Entities.PassModel.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=DB-SCAN:1521/PR;USER ID=userName;Password=password;Pooling=true;CONNECTION LIFETIME=20;INCR POOL SIZE=1;MAX POOL SIZE=1;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

when I publish into IIS if the first request goes to :
Public/* path
then I go to any page in :
Pages/* path
I got an error :

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

if the first request goes to Pages/*
everything is working fine.

and some times overnight when everything is working fine then in the morning the users get the same error

I tried both managed and classic pipeline, and impersonating in code

```
 var callerWindowsIdentity = Request.LogonUserIdentity as WindowsIdentity;
  using (callerWindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
            { 
//context code
}
```

but they don't work